# How can I add buttons to the sidebar?

Tags: templating

I can't find a way to include buttons on the correct place at the sidebar of my plugin.

So I noticed that on the sidebar markup, there's a div for buttons, there's created automatically:

[image]

I can easily add anything to the sidebar, I can include the buttons on the top, as you can see on the example, but my question is, how do I add the buttons to that div?

I couldn't find on the templates the correct place.

[EDIT]

Here's my template.

```
{% extends "_layouts/elementindex" %}
{% includeCssResource "crashC/css/crashC.css" %}

{% set title = "Entries" %}
{% set selectedTab = 'entries' %}
{% set elementType = "CrashC" %}
{% set docsUrl = '' %}

{% block sidebar %}
  <a href="http://##" class="btn submit">Download CSV</a>
  {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this one, actually, you can do this with:

**Javascript**: `Craft.elementIndex.addButton($('<a href="http:/##" class="btn submit" />').html('test'))`

**Template**: Just add a div with class `.buttons`, Craft's javascript will check for that and you won't get duplicated divs.

```
{% block sidebar %}
  <div class="buttons">
     <a href="http://##" class="btn submit">Download CSV</a>
  </div>
  {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Done.
I hope this helps others too.